# Form that changes class attribute to active

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a web page associated with 3 `<li>` and each has its own `onclick()` function. By default, one of them is active. Now I have a form, if this form is submitted I want it to take me to one of the other two `<li>`.

In other words, I want it to remove the active class from the default one, and add it to one of the other two. How can I do that?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="editor-nav">
    <li id="content-w" class="en-nav active">1. Add Status</li>
    <li id="setting-w" name="setting-w" class="en-nav">2. Upload Image</li>
    <li id="cover-w" class="en-nav">3. Upload Video</li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="be-large-post-align" id="firstdiv">
  <form class="" action="work.php" method="post">

    <textarea id="special" name="post" rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="What's on your mind, <?=$_SESSION['name']?>?"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submitMe" class="buttons-navbar btn btn-primary" value="POST" /></form>
</div>

<div class="be-large-post-align" id="seconddiv" style="display:none;">

  <form class="" action="work.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- <label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-file-selector">
      <input id="my-file-selector" type="file" multiple="multiple" style="display:none"
      onchange="$('#upload-file-info').html(this.files[0].name)">
      Button Text Here
      </label>
      <span class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info"></span> -->

    Select Image Files to Upload:
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    <textarea id="special" name="post2" rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="What's on your mind, <?=$_SESSION['name']?>?"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submitIt" class="buttons-navbar btn btn-primary" value="Upload" />
  </form>
</div>


<div class="be-large-post-align" id="thirddiv" style="display:none;">this is working! </div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" > </script> 
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>

 <script type = "text/javascript" >

  $("#setting-w").on("click", function() {
    $("#firstdiv").fadeOut(1, function() {
      $("#seconddiv").fadeIn(1, function() {});
      $("#thirddiv").fadeOut(1, function() {});
    });
  });

$("#content-w").on("click", function() {
  $("#seconddiv").fadeOut(0.1, function() {
    $("#firstdiv").fadeIn(0.1, function() {});
    $("#thirddiv").fadeOut(0.1, function() {});
  });
});

$("#cover-w").on("click", function() {
  $("#seconddiv").fadeOut(0.1, function() {
    $("#firstdiv").fadeOut(0.1, function() {});
    $("#thirddiv").fadeIn(0.1, function() {});
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: by mistake. excuse me

Comment: show us the code you have so far

Comment: please share your code and attempts

Comment: I added them now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data `attribute` to fade your div.

```js
$('.editor-nav li').click(function(e) {
  $('.editor-nav li').removeClass('active');

  var data = $(this).data('myval');
  if (data == "2" || data == "3") {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var tstDiv = data - 1;
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    $(document).find($('*[data-val="' + data + '"]')).fadeIn();
    $(document).find($('*[data-val="' + tstDiv + '"]')).fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="editor-nav">
    <li data-myval="1" id="content-w" class="en-nav active">1. Add Status</li>
    <li data-myval="2" id="setting-w" name="setting-w" class="en-nav">2. Upload Image</li>
    <li data-myval="3" id="cover-w" class="en-nav">3. Upload Video</li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div data-val="1" class="be-large-post-align" id="firstdiv">
  <form class="" action="work.php" method="post">

    <textarea id="special" name="post" rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="What's on your mind, <?=$_SESSION['name']?>?"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submitMe" class="buttons-navbar btn btn-primary" value="POST" /></form>
</div>

<div data-val="2" class="be-large-post-align" id="seconddiv" style="display:none;">

  <form class="" action="work.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- <label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-file-selector">
  <input id="my-file-selector" type="file" multiple="multiple" style="display:none"
  onchange="$('#upload-file-info').html(this.files[0].name)">
  Button Text Here
  </label>
  <span class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info"></span> -->

    Select Image Files to Upload:
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    <textarea id="special" name="post2" rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="What's on your mind, <?=$_SESSION['name']?>?"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submitIt" class="buttons-navbar btn btn-primary" value="Upload" />
  </form>
</div>


<div data-val="3" class="be-large-post-align" id="thirddiv" style="display:none;">this is working! </div>
```

After page submit if your page is reloaded page loose state. So set your value when page submit like:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'your form Number')
```

Get localStorage when page load like:

```
var formID = localStorage.getItem('key');
```

After that check for null before add class:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("key") != null) {
  (".editor-nav ul li").eq(formID ).addClass("active"); // Check this one on page load
}
```

Comment: Hello there. I guess you did not understand my question or maybe I did not make it clear. I already have it changing classes to active if I switch from one to another, but the problem here is the form. The form when it is submitted it takes me back to the default active li and that's not what I want. I have 3 forms for each li and what I want is when the form of one of them is submiited. Once it is submitted, it make its corresponding li active. In other words, I want the form to have action="work.php?activate this li"

Comment: Hello Shree, when submitting the second form for example, it still takes me to the first li

Comment: If your page reload when submit form2  page state is loose. You need to hold that state in 'LocalStorage' In page load catch that local storage value and add class on ul > li  using `eq(localstoragevalue);`

Comment: Can you show me how can I do this? I have no knowledge about this Local storage thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use removeClass() and addClass() if you wish to add/remove any class based on their id.

Example:

```
$("#setting-w").on("click", function(){
    $("#content-w").removeClass('active');
    $("#cover-w").removeClass('active');
    $("#setting-w").addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Hello Gan, yes I understand that but the problem is when the form submits everything resets